# Avocado Seedlings cold tolerance

Tags: seedlings, avocado

I have a couple of avocado seedlings grown from pip (can't help it, its an addiction - I know Im better off with grafted ones, and have those too !) - I'm running out of space on my Window Sill and can't steal any more space in the house - so I want to move my Avocado seedlings into my polytunnel.

We are going into Winter, and I expect the temperatures in the polytunnel to get pretty cold - but hopefully should stave off the frost.    Are Avocado seedlings which are only a few months old generally able to withstand temperatures around 0c ?

Comment: If you drape some floating row cover over them, but not letting them touch the plants, that should give you another.degree or more of protection.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily...they need zones 9-11 USDA.  That means the minimum temperatures are 20-30 degrees F.  Somewhere I've read that an avocado made it through minus degrees F.

What zone are you in?  What kind of soil?  If you only have a few days of super cold (below 20 degrees F) then row cloth and or newspaper will do.  You just have to be on top of things with the weather.  I'd be more apt to drag my avocados inside for the winter.  Newspaper is the best insulator of all.  I dragged all my houseplants one winter to a new home during below zero temperatures...14 hours.  All I did was wrap all my plants in newspaper and every single one made it.

Another trick is to use burlap and christmas lights.  String christmas lights all around your plant and then cover and tie with burlap.  If your plants are in pots then make sure to dig a hole, and sink your pot in that hole.  Lots of christmas lights and burlap and/or straw.  The roots are the weakest link in a plant and potted plants are particularly susceptible to cold getting to the roots.

Too much work to raise an avocado if one doesn't live in zone 9 to get lazy, grins.  ONE night below freezing will kill your plant.  A week at sub optimum temperatures will kill your plant.

Newspaper and row cloth are great if those avocados are planted in the ground.  In pots, I'd just take them in...depends on your zone.

Comment: btw, a polytunnel helps but if it isn't heated it is almost the same as not having a polytunnel.  I lost ours last fall with an early heavy snow.  Sigh.  The snow cover is a super insulator and all of my perennials, raspberries, boysenberries, asparagus, strawberries, herbs made it. Set 'em back an awful lot.  I live in zone 1b.  Just like most of Alaska.  We are working on a  self contained heated greenhouse whilst growing crops beneath the WOOD work.  What was I thinking to move here??

Comment: I am apparently in a zone equivalent to US hardiness zone 9B (but I'm in New Zealand, so we have just entered Winter).  Last winter the lowest temperature I recorded was -3.5c - I've only been here a bit over a year - last year we had about 10 days where the temperature was below.  I can't actually find incandescent christmas lights and don't have power near the polytunnel either.   My understanding is that the plants become more hardy once they are mature - unfortunately I don't know exactly what this implies !   I've just put them in a compost/cocopeat mix.

Comment: Ahhh...my best friend is a Kiwi.  Dang if you aren't the lucky one!!  Your zone is fine for growing avocados except for the exceptional freeze which is all it takes to get really really bummed.  No power?  Hummm.  No way to drag a good MAJOR electrical extension cord out there?  Or just bring the trees into a micro environment with the ability to have...what??  You can't find incandescent christmas lights?  So the best thing for you would be a ton of newspapers held in place with row cloth.  I think from what you've told me, you'll be fine with row cloth...and when it gets too cold add newspap